# Prestashop: switch theme on the fly and read cookie to check param in url

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty3

In order to setup an A/B testing (through GG Analytics), I planned to duplicate my current theme (for organisations purposes) in order to use the duplicated theme to do the alternate versions of the test. I use `Prestashop 1.4.9.2` .

What I already did, and works:

---

Added this to `/classes/FrontController.php`, in `displayHeader()` function *(I know I should override, but not the point ;))*:

```
if(isset($_GET['alternate']))
{
    $cookie->alternate = "1";
    $cookie->write();
}
```

---

Replaced in `/config/settings.inc.php` :

```
define('_THEME_NAME_', 'my_usual_theme');
```

by

```
if(isset($_GET['alternate']) || $cookie->alternate == "1")
{
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'my_alternate_theme');       
}
else
{
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'my_usual_theme');
}
```

---

This way, when I load my Prestahop url with "`?alternate`" at the end, it loads the alternative theme. Fine.

**PROBLEM**: I can't check the cookie value in `settings.inc.php`, and so when I click a link, it loads the default theme.

**QUESTION**:
Any clue to check the cookie in this file ? Or `config.inc.php` ? Or "re-define" the theme name in another file, overriding the `settings.inc.php` setup ?

Please note I check the cookie in another single file to validate the process, and it works well.  I also tried to use classic `setcookie` method, but if I can read/check, I can't write with this way... And for a reason I don't get, PHP activation in Smarty just don't work (tried to `setcookie` directly in template, but error 500 even with a simple echo).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way is moving `define('_THEME_NAME_', 'prestashop');` to place where you can use the global `$cookie` variable.

Regards

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to figure out, but I can't make it to at least "overwrite" the original `define('_THEME_NAME_', 'prestashop');`. All my different tries (playing also with `FrontController.php`, `defines.inc.php`) have no effect. Where I can use `$cookie`, I can't switch template.

Comment: Example of last stuff I did in `FrontController.php`:      `if (($cookie->alternate) && (_THEME_NAME_ == 'default'))
   {
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'alternate');
    echo _THEME_NAME_;
    die();
   }`  The echo shows `default`, not `alernate`. It's normal, as this define is already done in `settings.inc.php`, but I hoped I could "re-define" it later.

Comment: You can't overwrite default _THEME_NAME_, because variables assigned with define statement cannot be redefined (without runkit extension - http://php.net/runkit_constant_redefine). But you can remove default define statement from /config/settings.inc.php and define it in another place.