# Prestashop : use different theme for my IP address

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to use a different theme for my own IP address for development purpose in Prestashop.

How i can achieve that ?

I read this [Prestashop: switch theme on the fly and read cookie to check param in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282955/prestashop-switch-theme-on-the-fly-and-read-cookie-to-check-param-in-url)

But i don't know how to check IP address.

Thank you for your help
Quentin

Answer (score 1):

To get the user IP in PrestaShop:

```
Tools::getRemoteAddr();
```

So, for your needs:

```
$myIp = 'What ever your IP';
if (Tools::getRemoteAddr() == $myIP) {
    //TODO: Load theme A
} else {
    //TODO: Load theme B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you IP like so:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your.ip.address') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR this is ip proxy server for example not you, if you don't have proxy you REMOTE_ADDR is your ip address.

Answer (score 0):

see this quetion for more detail about how to get client Ip address. I formating code with coding style

```
function getClientIp() {

    $ipaddress = 'none';

    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    } elseif(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }elseif(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    }elseif(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')){ 
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    } elseif(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')) {
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    } elseif(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
       $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    } 

    return $ipaddress;
}

if(getClientIp() == '127.0.0.1') {
  // your instance theme
}
```